# set color to pie chart according to value color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I´m trying to set custom color to pie chart on dc js

I mean, every register has a category and that category has a color, the thing I have to do is set the category color to corresponding slice into the pie chart

this is how Im setting the chart

```
installationCategoryChart
.width(250)
.height(250)
.title(function (d) { return d.key + ' - Cantidad: ' + d.value + " - " + (d.value / StatusDim.groupAll().reduceCount().value() * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"; })
.dimension(CategoryDim)
.group(devicesPerCategory)
.innerRadius(50)
```

does anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [colorMixin.colors](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors__anchor) to set the color scale.

Since you know the names of your keys and the colors you want, it's easiest to specify an ordinal scale:

```
.colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(['key-1', 'key-2', 'key-3', 'key-4', 'key-5])
        .range(['#3f8', '#19e', '#86b', '#b37', '#661']))
```

(Pardon the random colors - not a best practice!)